# Check (USD) or Wire Foreign

Tags: foreign-exchange, check, wire-transfer

I am starting a few months job for an US company, but I am based in London. I will have a "vendor" role.

I have been offered two options to get paid: Check or Wire Foreign. What would you recommend?
I understand that wire may involve fees, but hopefully not too much, whereas check is slow, and may also involve fees or loosing money in the conversion to GBP.

Please, I have no experience, so any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend wire transfer.

I was in your position some years ago, and the US$ cheque took 6 weeks to clear. Wire transfer fees are generally a few tens of pounds, depending on the banks involved.